# trace inequality of positive definite matrices and diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

Assume that $A,B$ are $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ positive semi-definite matrices and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries taking values from $[0,1]$. Is it true that

$$tr(ACBC)\leq tr(AB)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, here's a quick counterexample.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1& 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $\mathrm{Tr}[AB] = 0$ but $\mathrm{Tr}[ACBC]=1$.

Comment: Your matrix $c$ is not diagonal

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua It is $\mathrm{diag}(1,0)$?

Comment: Yes, you're right so is your example

Comment: @Rammus, oh right, thanks!